# Scale Images in PHP

Tags: php, image-processing, jpeg, scale

for a project i have to do the folliwing things:

- check if a file is a valid image (JPEG, and if possible more formats)
- check width/height of an image (JPEG, and if possible more formats)
- scale an image (JPEG, and if possible more formats)

it´s forbidden to use external frameworks or scripts. only php-functions or self-written code are allowed.

so how is it possible with php?

Comment: Do you want to pay one or more programmers for the whole project? And how much? There're more benefits?

Comment: This sounds like homework!? The often suggested ImageMagick is an external framework/script. You should **look into PHP's file functions**. You can calculate new values and save the images once again. I did similiar functions in C as a GIMP plugin once. -- Check for example: http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Comment: This question is extremely broad as written. We're here to help you with _specific_ programming problems that you encounter after debugging or other dynamic or static analysis. If you can narrow down your question accordingly, please flag it for moderator review (click the 'flag' link under your question and select 'other').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** For the MIME Type [`getimagesize();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)  returns that. 
mime is the correspondant MIME type of the image. This information can be used to deliver images with the correct HTTP Content-type header:.

**2 .** See the `getimagesize();`

Returns an array with 7 elements. Index 0 and 1 contains respectively the width and the height of the image.

**3**. [ImageMagick](http://www.google.com.ng/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=scale%20image%20php&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-scaleimage.php&ei=0LeiTqCPJYv1sgaAmNTdBw&usg=AFQjCNFtTNgxVu2L_3WrUV4UggHPQ6xlXw) also does that effectively.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you know how to handle file uploads.

most php installs will come with one or both of the following image libraries.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php 
or 
http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Answer (score 0):

This one would tell you the image size (would work for many image formats - gif, jpeg, png, bmp at least), it returns width and height as array on success and false if it was unable to process the image. It requires GD PHP library:

```
$imageFilename = '/home/user/image.jpg';
$imageSize = @getimagesize($imageFilename);
if ($imageSize === false) {
// invalid image
}
list($width, $height) = $imageSize;
```

To resize, check the ImageMagick API (bitchy to install) or GD API (GD would be easier to use imho and it's more likely to have that one by default), I don't have ready code. I would recommend you to use either of them, not both to solve your problems.